# Lagrange Multipliers Dimensions

Tags: calculus, area, lagrange-multiplier

A farmer wishes to fence off a rectangular pasture along the bank of a river. The area of the pasture is 3200 $yd^2$. There is no fencing needed along the river bank. Find the dimensions of the pasture that'll require the least amount of fencing. $$\\$$

[image]

I'm not sure how to begin this problem.

I know the area is $lw$ = 3200.

Please help.

Comment: Try drawing a picture to help visualize what the question is asking.

Comment: I suppose we're to assume the river has a straight bank? It would make the problem more interesting if the bank was given by an arbitrary function, though.

Comment: @Χpẘ, it wouldn't matter what the function is for the river bank because you don't need fencing around there

Comment: @Bbot Imagine the riverbank runs "horizontally" on a graph in the shape of a sine wave, $f(x)=a\cdot \sin(bx+\frac{3\pi}{2})+a$, for scaling constants $a,b$. The "northwest" corner of the pasture is at the origin. The west fence would be length $w$, but the east fence would $w+\sin(bl+\frac{3\pi}{2})$. You could draw this if it isn't clear.

Comment: @Χpẘ, yes I agree with what you are saying but for this specific problem it doesn't state a function so just use the perimeter which doesn't include the river side. Thus, we use $x$+2$y$

Comment: @AmR You can see that if the right fence is moved a little to the left it will need to be longer to get to the river. If you continue moving it left it will get shorter, then longer, etc. for each turn of the river. Therefore it's necessary to know a function that describes the path of the river or else assume the river bank is straight. Depending on where you are getting this problem from (beginning calculus, advanced calculus, etc.), the details of the desired answer may vary. You could add what the source of the problem is to the OP.

Comment: @bbot See the diagram in the (recently updated) OP

Comment: Using Lagrange multipliers seems like overkill for this problem. You can very easily solve for $x$ or $y$ in terms of the other variable in the area formula and substitute into the formula for the perimeter.

Comment: @amd It's overkill if the river has a straight bank, but what if the river is undulating like in the picture in the OP?

Comment: @Χpẘ That’s not the problem at hand, though, crude illustration aside. If the bank undulates that’s a rather different problem since you’re going to need not only dimensions but also position to optimize the perimeter. Even so, if it’s possible to express one of the variables as a simple function of the other, why introduce a third unknown that doesn’t make finding the solution any simpler?

Comment: @Amd given the title and the picture, IMO that is exactly the problem at hand - given the possibility that the OP neglected to mention that the river bank's course could be described by a formula. Or maybe he didn't neglect to mention that. It's not possible to know authoritatively (except from OP and he hasn't said, despite comments asking for that). BTW I didn't ask anything about introducing a third variable, so not sure why you're mentioning your opinion on that.

Comment: @Χpẘ Given the actual *content* of the OP, it’s reasonably clear that this is an entry-level problem and that the bank is meant to be straight. It wouldn’t be a “rectangular pasture” otherwise. Re: introducing a third variable—how would you characterize the method of Lagrange multipliers, if not that?

Comment: @AMD there's evidence for both strictly rectangular and vaguely rectangular in the OP. Again, no authoritative answer to that question. It strikes me as odd that a lot of folks here are rigorous WRT math answers but not too rigorous WRT to interpreting math questions. You don't see people say "reasonably clear" when characterizing answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the pasture is a rectangle, the Area= $xy$= 3200.

The minimum fencing required is f($x$,$y$) = $x$+2$y$.$$\\$$
$fx$→ 1 =  λy

$\implies$ $\frac{1}{y}$ = λ

$fy$→ 2 =  λx

$\implies$ $\frac{2}{x}$ = λ

Set them equal and cross multiply:
$\frac{1}{y}$=$\frac{2}{x}$

$\implies$ 2$y$=$x$ $$\\$$
Remember that the Area: $xy$= 3200 and we just found what $x$ equals.

$xy$= 3200

= (2$y$)$y$ = 3200

= 2$y^2$ = 3200

= $y^2$ = 1600

= $y$ = ±40

$y$ = 40 because you can't have a negative yard. $$\\$$

Remember that 2$y$=$x$ and we just found what $y$ equals.

2$y$=$x$

= 2(40) = $x$

= $x$ = 80 $$\\$$
**So your dimension are 80 x 40 yards.**

Comment: how did you get $x$+2$y$?

Comment: I suggest you draw a visual

Comment: Make one side the river, one side the $x$, and the other two sides as $y$

Comment: ohhh, okay. I get it. thank you!

Comment: Just for fun, I get the following if the curve of the river is given by $g(x)$, and $f(l,w)$ is the length of the fence: $f(l,w)=g(0)+w+g(l)+w$ and $\int_0^l g(x) dx + lw = 3200$, so $f$ in terms of $l$ is $f(l)=g(0)+g(l)+\frac{2(3200-\int_0^l g(x) dx)}{l}$. This gives the same result if $g(x)=0$ for all $x$